# Is there a way to get R print ouput as string?

Tags: r, string, representation

**Is there a simple way to get the output of print as a string variable?** Something like:

```
output_string = print(object)
```

the function `print()` imho has a rather "intelligent" way of representing objects respectively object information as strings. Hence it would be useful to be able to process this output.

I thought all `print()` does is calling the `toString()` method on the object it is called with. However doing `toString(object)` gives different results and I'd like to get the string that `print(object)` generates... just not as output to the console but stored in a variable.

---

My context:
I create a random forest model. Doing `print(rf)` gives me some basic stats about the model, that I'd like to write to a log file, whereas `toString(rf)` gives me a huge string with what seems to be an actual string representation of the full tree (splits etc). So I'd like to do:

```
rf = randomForest(...)
fileConn = file("rf.log")
writeLines(c(">>> random forest:", print(rf) ), fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

I tried to get some information about this from the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html), but this doesn't seem to be an advertised feature. There is something about `invisible(rf)`, I was hoping this would do what I want, but it merely seems to copy the object.

Comment: `help("capture.output")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be what you are after ?

```
# As vector:
res_vec <- capture.output(
  print(df)
)

cat(res_vec)

# As scalar:
res_scalar <- paste0(capture.output(
  print(df)
), collapse = "\n")

cat(res_scalar)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Mason_Id = sample(c("Mason1", "Mason2","Mason3","Mason4","Mason5","Mason6"), 12, T),
Registration_Date = c("01-08-2020", "01-08-2020","05-08-2020","07-08-2020",
"02-09-2020", "02-09-2020","02-09-2020",
"03-09-2020","04-09-2020","01-10-2020","02-10-2020",
"06-10-2020"), Token_Count = runif(12, 10, 100), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a look at the `sink()` function as it captures all the output into a text file that is normally shown in the console.

From `?sink` :

```
sink("sink-examp.txt")
i <- 1:10
outer(i, i, "*")
sink()
```

Comment: good point... although this doesn't give me the output of `print()` as a variable, it is still a useful option to circumvent needing it as a variable if direct output is what I need.

Comment: True - but maybe (as a workaround) you could save the output and read it again into R and save it as a string variable? Not sure if this is such a good idea though. But if you _really_ need the output in a string variable...

Comment: ... then I'd use above option with `capture.output()` which works fine :)